# django convert to date type (TypeError)

Tags: python, django, python-datetime

I'm trying to get data from excel cells (number format) and convert them to date type in Django 1.7.7:

```
import datetime as dt

birthdate   =dt.date.fromtimestamp(sheet.row_values(idx)[63]).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

but got this error:

```
 File "t3_import2.py", line 46, in <module>
  birthdate   =dt.date.fromtimestamp(sheet.row_values(idx)[63]).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
TypeError: a float is required
```

Why is it complaining when I explicitly cast it to float?

Comment: What date / time is `sheet.row_values(idx)[63]`?

Answer (score 0):

`sheet.row_values(idx)[63]` is not a float.

If I understand right, `fromtimestamp` expects a POSIX timestamp, which is a vector representing the number of seconds elapsed from a given time to the time/date it represents. I can't see what `sheet.row_values(idx)[63]` is from your post, but I'd bet Python it taking it as an `int`.

> classmethod date.fromtimestamp(timestamp)¶
>
> Return the local date
>   corresponding to the POSIX timestamp, such as is returned by
>   time.time(). This may raise ValueError, if the timestamp is out of the
>   range of values supported by the platform C localtime() function. It’s
>   common for this to be restricted to years from 1970 through 2038. Note
>   that on non-POSIX systems that include leap seconds in their notion of
>   a timestamp, leap seconds are ignored by fromtimestamp().

try this:

```
x = float(sheet.row_values(idx)[63])
birthdate = dt.date.fromtimestamp(x).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```